# Why in the annotation-based Spring app @Value default value is getting resolved to null?

Tags: java, spring, properties

In my class, I have 2 private fields that are pre-populated via @Value annotation. Although the value is getting read correctly from .properties file, its default value is never applied if in .properties file it's not set.

I have tried with creating PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean and specifying location to the file: "classpath:application.properties". These are my properties:

```
@Value("${year:2019}")
private Integer year;
```

resources/application.properties:

```
year=
```

When the year is set, Integer year receives the right value. If it remains empty, I expect default value (2019) to be set, but it remains null.

Spring version: 5.1.8.RELEASE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is null because your properties file sets it to blank. If you remove the year= from the properties file you should get the default value.

Comment: So it is not possible to keep it optional, i.e. blank?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but by putting year= in the properties file is deliberately setting the value. if you don't want to set it then leave it out of the properties file.

Comment: I thought if nothing comes after =, it is considered null and then default value should come into play. But ok, what you say also makes sense, so I accept it as the right answer.